# VBA runtime error: save PowerPoint Presentation as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, powerpoint

I create a Powerpoint presentation from an Excel workbook (both version 2016) and in the end I want to save the presentation as pdf.

I tried:

```
filenamePPT = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & "_Statusbericht_" & ApName & "_KW" & KW & ".pdf"

ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat filenamePPT, ppFixedFormatTypePDF
```

and am getting:

> runtime error: -2147221165 (80040154): class not registered

in the second line.

In my opinion, I did everything accordingly to [the Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.exportasfixedformat).

**EDIT:**

All relevant references are added:

- PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Office 16.0 Object Library
- Forms 2.0 Object Library
- ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
- ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library

**EDIT2:**

```
Public createslide6 As Boolean
Public ChartrngVONstring As String
Public ChartrngBISstring As String
Public filenameEXCEL As String
Public user As String


Sub VBA_AP_Status_v1()


Dim year As Double
Dim ZKW1 As Double
Dim ZKW2 As Double
Dim ZKW3 As Double
Dim ZKW4 As Double
Dim ZKW5 As Double
Dim ZKW6 As Double
Dim ZKW7 As Double
Dim ZKW8 As Double
Dim MS1Dauer As Double
Dim MS2Dauer As Double
Dim MS3Dauer As Double
Dim MS4Dauer As Double
Dim MS5Dauer As Double
Dim MS6Dauer As Double
Dim MS7Dauer As Double
Dim MS8Dauer As Double
Dim minScale As Double
Dim maxScale As Double
Dim e As Integer
Dim yearString As String
Dim nextyearString As String
Dim StandortVar As String
Dim filenamePPT As String
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout

Dim AllgShape As Object
Dim MSShape As Object
Dim MSTShape As Object
Dim BemShape As Object
Dim APUShape As Object
Dim LGShape As Object
Dim HLShape As Object
Dim SlideNum As Object
Dim Fußzeile As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide1 As Object
Dim mySlide2 As Object
Dim mySlide3 As Object
Dim mySlide4 As Object
Dim mySlide5 As Object
Dim mySlide6 As Object
Dim mySlide7 As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim ppTextbox As Object
Dim Chart1 As Object
Dim ChartLegend As Object
Dim MSPfeilLang As Object
Dim MSPfeilKurz As Object
Dim MSDreieck1 As Object
Dim MSDreieck2 As Object
Dim MSDreieck3 As Object
Dim MSDreieck4 As Object
Dim MSDreieck5 As Object
Dim MSDreieck6 As Object
Dim RisikenTable As Object



user = Environ("username")
year = Format(Date, "yyyy")
yearString = Format(Date, "yyyy")
nextyearString = Format(Date, "yyyy") + 1


'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add


  myPresentation.ApplyTemplate "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\AP_Status_Vorlage.thmx"


'Add slides to the Presentation
  Set mySlide1 = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutCustom)       'an pos 1     '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
  Set mySlide2 = myPresentation.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutTitleOnly)


  Set ppTextbox = mySlide1.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 80, 800, 80)




~ 2k lines of code were deleted here





filenameEXCEL = "C:\users\" & user & "\Desktop\Daten_Statusbericht_" & ApName & "_KW" & KW & "_" & Format(Date, "dd_mm_yy")
filenamePPT = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & "_Statusbericht_" & ApName & "_KW" & KW & ".pdf"

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active // OPTIONAL
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

'SAVING & CLOSING Powerpoint

  ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat filenamePPT, ppFixedFormatTypePDF

  'If Not GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application") Is Nothing Then
    'GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application").Quit
  'End If


'Call CloseAndSaveExcelApplication

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: May I see your complete code?

Comment: @BigBen I edited the question. Yes I did add the object library for PP

Comment: @SiddharthRout unfortunately that's not possible. It is 3k lines long and contains sensitive information. Basically there is nothing else which has relevance for the saving process

Comment: I am more interested in how are you working with powerpoint objects (declaring and initializing objects)

Comment: @SiddharthRout is there an object involved in this commands? In the beginning, I am declaring `dim xy as Object` several times but not for this saving process. It does make no difference if I write `dim filenamePPT as String` beforehand. Do I have to `set ActivePresentation = something`?

Comment: Did you just upgrade MS Office? Also have you tried to latebind instead of earlybind?

Comment: `@SiddharthRout is there an object involved in this commands?` There is nothing wrong with the syntax of the code posted in the question. I was hoping to find some clue in your code and hence I was asking for the code...

Comment: The class not registered error is  usually caused for any application with unregistered dll files because of which windows cannot recognize the file. And hence I asked `Did you just upgrade MS Office?` ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I just added some code to the question but I don't think that it makes any difference. As you can probably see I am quite a noob with VBA and programming in general. No I did not upgrade it. I have seen some suggestions to "repair Office" via the Windows settings. Do you think that's worth a shot?

Comment: `I have seen some suggestions to "repair Office" via the Windows settings` Yes I thought of that too but wanted to suggested that as a last resort

Comment: I understood what the problem is. One moment. Posting an answer. Fortunately you do not have to repair office :)

Comment: `It is 3k lines long and contains ...` On a completely different note,  I am 100% sure that your 3k lines can be drastically reduced :)

Comment: `On a completely different note, I am 100% sure that your 3k lines can be drastically reduced :)` 
you are certainly right about that and at some point I will try to make it more efficient, but for now this is sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dim PowerPointApp As Object
>
> Dim myPresentation As Object
>
> Dim mySlide1 As Object

You have used late binding and early binding together. Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oPPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPPPrsn As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oPPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    
    Dim FlName As String
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant file
    FlName = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\test.pdf"
    
    '~~> Establish an PowerPoint application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oPPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oPPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    oPPApp.Visible = True
    
    '~~> Open the relevant powerpoint file
    Set oPPPrsn = oPPApp.Presentations.Add
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant slide which has the shape
    Set oPPSlide = oPPPrsn.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutCustom)
    
    oPPPrsn.ExportAsFixedFormat FlName, ppFixedFormatTypePDF
End Sub
```